# how do you integrate jenkins with a rails project correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins

I understand that there are other posts in regards to this but there are two issues with my setup:

1. When the jasmine-ci throws an exception my build is still passing instead of failing.
2. Is this the most eloquent way of doing this (ssh lines + rake tasks)? I feel like there should be a prettier/nicer way of integrating ruby+jenkins?

[image: Rake issues]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [ci_reporter](https://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter) gem.

http://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2011/09/25/rail-3-1-ci-setup-with-jenkins-test-unit-simplecov-on-os-x-lion/

This gem wrap spec rake task and makes xml output which could be understand by Jenkins and report failure if tests don't pass.

I think Jenkins doesn't know much about Ruby and RVM and your project environment. This is why you need to write custom shell task, specifying version of Ruby, database.yml config and so on.

Good luck with Jenkins, but I can't wait for private Travis CI release)

Comment: I also recommend to read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644774/protect-jenkins-with-nginx-http-auth-except-callback-url