# Protect Jenkins with nginx http auth except callback url

Tags: proxy, nginx, jenkins, http-authentication

I installed jenkins on my server and I want to protected it with nginx http auth so that requests to:

```
http://my_domain.com:8080
http://ci.my_domain.com
```

will be protected except one location:

```
http://ci.my_domain.com/job/my_job/build
```

needed to trigger build. I am kinda new to nginx so I stuck with nginx config for that.

```
upstream jenkins {
  server  127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
  listen x.x.x.x:8080;
  server_name *.*;

  location '/' {
    proxy_pass http://jenkins;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /path/.htpasswd;    
  }
}
```

I tried smth like above config but when I visit `http://my_domain.com:8080` there is no http auth.

Comment: An almost identical clone of that works fine for me; you're not using 8080 for both the upstream and for nginx in the real config, are you?

Comment: What do you mean in real config? As I understand nginx can't catch 8080 port request so I need to block it with firewall and just proxy ci subdomain requests to x.x.x.x:8080

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to solve this problem. At first we need to uncheck "Enable security" option at Manage Jenkins page. With security disabled we can trigger our jobs with requests like `http://ci.your_domain.com/job/job_name/build`.

If you want to add token to trigger URL we need to Enable Security, choose "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy" and give Admin rights to Anonymous user. After it in Configure page of your project will be "Trigger builds remotely" option where you can specify token so your request will look like `JENKINS_URL/job/onru/build?token=TOKEN_NAME`

So with disabled security we need to protect http://ci.your_domain.com with nginx http_auth except urls like `/job/job_name/build'`.

And of course we need to hide 8080 port from external requests. Since my server is on Ubuntu I can use **iptables** firewall:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -s localhost -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
```

But! On ubuntu (I am not sure about other linux oses) iptables will disappear after reboot. So we need to save them with:

```
iptables-save
```

And it is not the end. With this command we just get a file with iptables. On startup we need to load iptables and the easiest way is to use 'uptables-persistent' package:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules
```

Take a closer look at iptables if needed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Saving_iptables and good luck with Jenkins!

And there is good example for running jenkins on subdomain of your server: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Hudson+behind+Nginx